# ThinkorSwim (Ameritrade) API pulling stock data

Tags: python, api

I am trying to pull some data from the TOS API. I believe I am missing the payload params but not sure if this is something I need because I created the final string for the `get` request.

```
apiKey = "APIKeyAPIKeyAPIKeyAPIKeyAPIKeyAP"
ticker = "TSLA"
periodType = "day"
period = "10"
frequencyType = "minute"
frequency = "1"

apicall = "https://api.tdameritrade.com/v1/marketdata/"+ticker+"/pricehistory?apikey="+apiKey+"&periodType="+periodType+"&period="+period+"&frequencyType="+frequencyType+"&frequency="+frequency+"&needExtendedHoursData=true HTTP/1.1"

jsonData = requests.get(apicall,headers = {'User-agent': 'Chrome/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0'}).json()
```

The code does not fail but the `jsonData` variable get assigned:

```
{'error': 'Bad request.'}
```

How can I correctly put this string together so it pulls data. I put the link in browser window and got JSON data back so I know my syntax is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

According to their [API playground](https://developer.tdameritrade.com/price-history/apis/get/marketdata/%7Bsymbol%7D/pricehistory), you need to add authorization header. The token can be obtained via their [OAuth API](https://developer.tdameritrade.com/authentication/apis/post/token-0).

```
jsonData = requests.get(apicall,headers = {'User-agent': 'Chrome/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0', 'authorization': 'Bearer <access token>'}).json()
```